# VS 2010 Won't open/Crashes each time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have spent at least 5 hours researching and trying to solve this problem. I have reinstalled VS, I have tried it on a different user account, I have deleted certain registry files, I have literally done everything I could possibly find.

I was using VS and quit the application on accident. I opened it again and I kept getting a black screen when I opened my project. I decided to try opening VS itself instead and same thing. There are a few error messages I have been able to get which I will provide.

There was also a instance where the program opened however it was all black with the words "Rea" at the top left.

http://rizzit.net/direct/mvesLJF.jpg

This is a trace from the EventViewer:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.BadImageFormatException
Stack:
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.RangeBase.OnMaximumChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry ByRef, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ScheduleTransfer(Boolean)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.NewValueAvailable(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32, System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView, System.Object, Boolean)
   at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.ScheduleTransferOperation(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindOperation.Invoke()
   at MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.ProcessCrossThreadRequests()
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.WorkerThreadElementContainer.UIWorkerThreadStart(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(System.Object)
```

I was able to get the error again after "resetting stuff"

[image]

Comment: Suggestions... check Event Viewer for any error logs (and if there are any, update your question with them), try resetting Visual Studio settings using the [`/ResetSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241273(v=vs.100).aspx) switch.

Comment: I have used all of the /Reset... commands. Nothing is working.

Comment: Can you use latest instead of 2010? Did you install all service packs/patches?

Comment: Does this just happen with a particular solution or is it even when loading VS without a project?

Comment: It's whenever I open VS

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I finally found out what was wrong. Somehow my .NET frameworks got corrupted and to fix it, simply uninstall all frameworks and re download them.